# Was Thor putting the Helicarrier in danger by dropping his hammer on floor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, thor-marvel, the-avengers-2012

In the *Avengers* movie, Thor dropped *Mjölnir* on the floor of the Helicarrier. As proof, I can remind you that the Hulk tried to lift *Mjölnir* on the Helicarrier.

Due to Odin's enchantment, was *Mjölnir* limiting the altitude of the Helicarrier and putting it in danger? (According to aerodynamics, it's essential to go up or down, even by a very small amount, due to non-ideal air conditions for flying.)

Or was it not dangerous because the condition of being worthy or unworthy to lift *Mjölnir* is not applicable to an artificial object like the Helicarrier?

Comment: See also: [Would Mjolnir, if loose in Hulk's cage, move?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16385/5184) and [Can Thor's hammer be wielded by anyone in outer space?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7139/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 It not a duplicate as I am not asking whether Helicarrier would go down or not.

Comment: Obviously, I disagree, and that's fine. Leave it up to the community. All of those questions/answers deal with the worthiness enchantment versus actual downward forces - and that's the crux of your question.

Answer (score 8):

Mjolner doesn't need to do something clever with mass to prevent it being picked up - it could simply be glued to the surface. And from the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mjolnir):

> This enchantment surrounding Mjolnir prevents it from being wielded by anyone save those who have been found worthy. ... To anyone else, Mjolnir cannot be lifted from the ground nor wrested from Thor’s grip.

Note the second part heavily implies it's not related to gravity/mass directly, as it's stuck *in his grip*.

If you assume the difficulty in lifting Mjolner is not related to mass shenanigans, then it's unlikely the Helicarrier was at risk.

Comment: Did I say mass? Read the question again...

Comment: `it could simply be glued to the surface` ~> Then, by-passing Odin's enchantment would be easier when you can lift the surface.

Comment: @SachinShekhar My point is it doesn't *need* to be a constant downward force to meet the requirements of the worthiness enchantment. All it needs to do is directly counteract whatever force is being used to lift it - this could be an attractive force with the surface it is on, extra mass/weight, or some other possibility that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Again, just lift up the surface.. compatible with your point in previous comment. In *Thor* movie, all they needed to cut the land below it & lift the land.. oh, the silly hammer just care about gluing with the land.. move the piece of land to research lab or museum.

Comment: So, your point is wrong...

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes, that's potentially all they would need to do. Think about it: that's exactly what's happening with the Helicarrier - they're moving the "land" Mjolner is on, with no visible response from the enchantment. I'd consider it likely there's some sort of magic-logic that prevents Mjolner from being moved by living creatures (possibly including the odd mechanical intelligence?) and being moved by non-living things (like the Helicarrier).

Comment: @SachinShekhar An additional consideration: the enchantment is a plot device, and I haven't seen any definition of the enchantment that nails it down in unambiguous terms. It will depend heavily on the writer. For example, if I can't move it myself, could I move it with a crane or bulldozer? What if it was on a boat I was piloting? When does that break down?

Comment: @thegrinner absolutely -- the enchantment is magic, and seems to operate by rules of "whichever definition works for the plot". Maybe the magic conveys some minor intelligence/decision-making-capability on the hammer (or the universe around it). Clearly it was able to move while on the helicarrier. It wasn't able to be dislodged from the earth by the truck in Thor. It doesn't seem to keep the earth from turning, because we go from night to day in Thor. Obviously it is not fixed in place relative to the universe, just relative to plot considerations.

Comment: Damn... everyone is talking about moving the hammer. The enchantment was actually around lifting.

Comment: @PeterL As for the Earth, Earth isn't lifting the hammer from its gravity well.

Comment: @thegrinner Helicarrier was obviously moving the land, but the enchantment advocates about lifting. Whether Helicarrier would lift it is the main point of confusion. If you think Helicarrier can lift it, give me citations..

Answer (score 5):

As per [@phantom42's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42885/was-thor-putting-the-helicarrier-in-danger-by-dropping-his-hammer-on-floor/42899?noredirect=1#comment79573_42899), the actual enchantment we see placed on Mjölnir in the Marvel Cinematic universe is:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

It's possible that Mjölnir has some non-enchantment-based property - e.g. mass, magnetism - that makes it impossible to *lift* it without "the power of Thor" (whatever that is).

However, I think the events of the movies make more sense if the hammer has no such property, but the enchantment also prevents the unworthy from *wielding* Mjölnir.

[The word "wield" implies control and intention](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wield). When Thor drops Mjölnir while on board the Helicarrier, the pilot isn't using Mjölnir for a purpose just by controlling the vehicle with Mjölnir aboard, so I don't think he/she is *wielding* it. Hence the enchantment doesn't need to restrict the Helicarrier's movement at this point.

In contrast, when a truck driver was attempting to extract Mjölnir from the ground with his truck in *Thor*, the enchantment wasn't having any of that, as the driver was trying to control Mjölnir - i.e. attempting to wield it - via his truck.

The lift/wield distinction is discussed further in answers to other similar questions:

- [Exceptions to Mjölnir’s immovability in the comics, which also discusses the Helicarrier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/38315/440)
- [Mjölnir moving if Thor dropped it in the Hulk cage in the movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16406/440)
- [Mjölnir being moved in space in the comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16595/440)

And [the Marvel Movies Wikia describes the enchantment in terms of wielding](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir#Powers_and_Abilities), although it doesn't provide any sources.

Comment: In the movie, the enchantment is actually over who "holds"["Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWmlWA_jb7w).

Comment: @phantom42: gotcha. Is that the enchantment that stops the unworthy from lifting it though? Does the hammer have a non-enchantment-based property (e.g. mass) that prevents people without the power of Thor from lifting it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not super familiar with Thor/Mjolnir's backstory and limitations. This is the only enchantment we see actually being cast during the movie.

Comment: @phantom42: sure, me neither. I'll edit my answer to reflect that - my idea about the "wield" enchantment is pretty much just me trying to make sense of what happens in the movie.

Comment: I absolutely agree. "Wield" definitely makes more sense from what we see in the course of the movies so far. I'll do some more digging tonight to see if I can find out more. Or this may be a place for a new question.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think the idea is that the 'power of Thor' includes the ability to use Mjolnir.

Comment: @Keen: gotcha. That inscription could really do with some clarifying footnotes.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Odin's not one for fine print.

Comment: Previously, the answer was fine.. which was around wield word... now, the answer sucks.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I edited too much! Although the main bit I added clarifies what the enchantment actually is, which I think is important as your question mentioned “the condition of being worthy or unworthy to lift Mjölnir” — I don’t think that phrasing is used in the movie.

Comment: There are many enchantments on Mjolnir. The one you listed is irrelevant here.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: "There are many enchantments on Mjolnir." In the movies, there's one: the one that I listed. Unless I've missed one?