# Why can't this truck lift Mjolnir but a Helicarrier can?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

Stan Lee said

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.

Why this truck can't lift Mjolnir ? But

The Helicarrier is in flight and it is lifting Mjolnir.

(Thor hangs his hammer on coat rack)

I don't understand. Why is this different? Isn't this truck worthy enough?

Comment: @Mwr247 Seems closely related, but slightly different. As it is established inanimate objects can, so why could the truck not?

Comment: @Daishozen - Thor can **put it** places that are mobile

Comment: That's just the most relevant one I found. [There's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16385/56571) [no](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16568/56571) [shortage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42885/56571) [of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/88079/56571) [Mjolnir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123459/56571) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16385/56571) (each of those is a link, and there's still plenty more).

Comment: @Valorum Sounds like a good answer to me, but I still think it is different enough to warrant a separate question from above. And side note, is there a sci-fi question that you don't know the answer to?

Comment: @Daishozen - My knowledge of DCEU (especially the TV shows) is very limited indeed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the coat rack scene shouldn't really be considered as canon; I believe it's part of a humorous short with one of the movies.

Comment: If a truck being operated by a man to move it can work then ironman in his suit should be able to as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The Truck

The truck is trying to brute force move the Mjolnir because the owner is trying to move it.

## The Helicarrier

The Helicarrier isn't trying to move Mjolnir. It moved with Thor and it would be rather silly for Thor to board a craft and not have it move along with that craft. Note that when Hulk tries to move Mjolnir, it doesn't move for him.

## The hatrack

Thor placed Mjolnir there. We don't ever see Mjolnir be heavy, just immobile should someone "unworthy" try to move it. I would assumed that if Hulk came in, he'd be unable to remove it from the hatrack.

---

Ultimately, the implication of the statement on the hammer is that if someone **desires** to move/wield Mjolnir, and it deems them unworthy, they (and anything they use to that end, like a truck)will fail.

If a worthy person moves it onto something mobile, it seems it will stay on that craft until someone worthy removes it, regardless of where that craft would travel.

Comment: I this is the best answer about Mjolnir that I have ever heard. Thank you very much. Now it is clear to me. (If the Helicarrier pilots desires to move the hammer, they will fail like the truck.)

Comment: The Helicarrier - In the theater, I was so convinced Thor wasn't carrying around Mjolnir was because if he put it down, the Helicarrier would have crashed. This was later supported when it took so long for the hammer to be called during the hulk fight because I figured it was left on the ground