# How does Hulk lift Mjolnir in Ultimate Avengers movie?

Tags: marvel, avengers, thor-marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In the [Ultimate Avengers movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0491703/), Hulk initially struggles to lift [Mjolnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_%28comics%29), but eventually does and uses it against Thor. How is this possible?

I think it's been well established that only those worthy can lift it. Are the rules somehow different in Marvel's Ultimate universe/storyline? Is Hulk's brute strength overcoming Odin's enchantment?

[image: Hulk lifting Mjolnir]
[image: Hulk again lifts Mjolnir]

Comment: wow, i just saw the clip and came here, i guess this is the right place!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The Ultimate Thor from Marvel Earth #1610 was believed to be wielding a version of Mjolnir but it is revealed the hammer is not actually the magical device known in the Marvel Universe #616.**

[image]

In the Ultimate Marvel imprint title the Ultimates' first two series, the alternate universe version of Thor wields a weapon that while called Mjolnir is a hybrid of hammer and axe.

The [Ultimate Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Thor) entry on Wikpedia points out:

> However, the ax/hammer hybrid primarily wielded by the character is
>   considered to be the "Ultimate" version of Mjolnir, as revealed in
>   Ultimate Power #9. However in the Ultimate Thor miniseries it is
>   revealed that the original axe hammer is no longer necessary, as it's
>   not the real Mjolnir but instead, Dr. Braddock gives Thor tech-armor,
>   and Thor suggests to turn the power supply into a hammer. It is stated that this version of the hammer is not restricted by the worthiness test.

Even when Thor wielded the true hammer Mjolnir, the Earth #1610 version did not have an enchantment making it unable to be used by the unworthy. It was stolen and used several times by various villains, Magneto, Gregory Stark and by Captain America. When the Children of Tomorrow slaughtered the Asgardians, triggering the second Ragnorok, Mjolnir was hidden with Thor's son Modi in the Room with No Doors, in an attempt to keep it safe until Asgard may be restored to its former glory. Thor returned to Earth and he was given a Stark-enhanced version of the EDI power harness and the axe-hammer he wielded previously.

[image]

**Stark-enhanced EDI Harness and Techno-Mjolnir**

Comment: Your answers are so thorough! So just being really strong is all that is necessary to wield this ax/hammer version of Mjolnir?

Comment: Correct. Or having magnetic powers in the case of Magneto. But without the harness, you simply won't get the bang for the buck since they are technically a linked pair. The hammer backed with incredible strength makes it a terrifying weapon. When Thor was using it, he was more powerful than a Class 100 metahuman, making him one of the most physically powerful humans on Marvel Earth #1610.

Comment: So Thor really was crazy? He was just a normal guy with a power belt in Ultimates 2?

Comment: No he was not crazy.

Comment: @MikeBrown sorry I'm late to the party. When Loki made it seem that Thor was just a crazy ex-nurse, he was blending the truth with fiction. Certain aspects of his story - such as the power harness & hammer being constructs - were true, while others - such as Thor being crazy - were lies designed to make the Ultimates doubt him.

Comment: When you say "Class 100 metahuman" are you talking about something like what is shown in this chart? http://www.angelfire.com/mn2/tisthammerw/characters/exp.html

Answer (score -3):

He's got the Super-Soldier Serum in his body too, that's why.

Comment: So far your answer is purely speculative. Do you have any evidence to back up your conjecture?

Answer (score -3):

i thought that the hammer and belt were linked by some sort of gravity field that only canceled out if you wore the belt? The hulk was just strong enough to overcome this?

Comment: This isn't an answer. These are two questions and that is better as a comment.

Comment: I suppose this is intended as an answer, despite the question marks, but it's purely speculative. Do you have any evidence to back up your conjecture?

Answer (score -3):

The Hulk can lift Mjolnir because he is strong enough. Mjolnir is about strength.

Comment: Mjolnir, traditionally isn't about strength, but worthiness. But in this Ultimate universe case, it is about strength.

Comment: If it's about strength, maybe he's moving the earth.