# How was Loki not crushed by Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

In the Thor movie, Thor puts Mjolnir  on top of Loki at the end of the movie to stop him from moving.

Why did this not crush Loki?

And if it did **not** crush him, why could he not just roll out from under it?

Comment: Related: [Can Thor's hammer be wielded by anyone in outer space?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7139/1234)

Comment: Ah HA! THAT was the thread I read for this answer :)

Comment: Thor didn't put it on the floor, he put it on Loki.  If it had simple crushed through his feeble body and landed on the floor, Loki would have caused it to move, which the enchantment would have prevented.  I bet the hammer wanted to crush him, though.

Comment: Because Thor didn't bash Mjolnir onto Loki, he gently placed it there.

Comment: Same reason it didn’t crush the Hulk in the Avengers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Quick and dirty answer <strike>without references</strike>?

Because the reason Thor's hammer can't be moved isn't merely because it's super HEAVY; Odin's enchantment on it means it can't be moved by anyone of insufficient "worth." Thus, Mjolnir isn't heavy enough to crush Loki, nor is Loki of sufficient worth to move it or roll out from under it.

[Mjolnir](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mjolnir) or the Marvel Wiki.

"Worthiness Enchantment: This enchantment surrounding Mjolnir prevents it from being wielded by anyone save those who have been found worthy or anyone Thor deems acceptable to wield Mjolnir for a time; certain Asgardians, such as Skurge, have successfully lifted its handle from the ground, but not entirely lift Mjolnir itself. Thus far, this includes Thor, the Awesome Android, Odin, Tiwaz, Red Norvell, Beta Ray Bill, Bor and Captain America. To anyone else, Mjolnir cannot be lifted from the ground nor wrested from Thor’s grip."

Comment: +1 for a good concise answer. If you could hunt down the references for this, it'd be an even better answer.

Comment: In the movie universe, we can see it's not super heavy in *The Avengers*, as it doesn't bring down the Helicarrier when it's on the floor of it.

Comment: Also, if the weight were what was important, I'm pretty sure The Hulk could budge it at least a *little* :)

Comment: Superman and Wonder Woman have also both wielded Mjolnir during crossovers.

Answer (score -1):

Thor's hammer is strong. One can not simply roll out from Thor's hammer even if they're a god. Maybe if Loki was a human he would get crushed or have a few broken ribs, though lets not forget Loki is very strong. He could even of used some magic. Thor's hammer is very strongly linked to Thor's will, I doubt Thor would of wanted Loki dead.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a picture from the scene in question, where Loki is pinned to the Bifrost by having Mjolnir placed on top of him.

[image: Loki held down by Mjolnir]

Here is a good look at the costume Loki was wearing in *Thor*.

[image: Loki in Thor (2011)]

The simple answer is that Mjolnir was placed on top of the breastplate that Loki is wearing. It seems safe to assume that there is enough room between Loki's chest and his breastplate for him to breathe, as otherwise he wouldn't ever be able to breathe while wearing it.

Plus, we have to remember that Mjolnir was only on top of Loki for a handful of seconds, half a minute at most. After that, Thor realises that he must destroy the Bifrost, and calls Mjolnir to him in order to do so.