# If Thor's hammer is so heavy, why does it not crush the table it is on?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, thor-marvel, super-hero

After watching the latest [Avenger's tv spot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGwuoYKhqx8) , I couldn't help but wonder, if Thor's hammer is so heavy that the Avengers can't lift it, why does it not crush the coffee table it's placed on?

Comment: the hammer is not, to heavy that people cant pick it up, its magically impossible to move, unless you meet the requirements, so being immovable allows it to act as a weight, but it itself is not extremely heavy. physically anyone can lift it.

Comment: If you think it's weight that prevents others from lifting it, then you aren't paying attention :-)

Comment: People without superhuman strength (e.g. Storm) have been able to lift Mjolnir, proving that it is *not* an issue of weight at all.

Comment: See also: [How does Mjolnir determine 'worth'?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4404/how-does-mjolnir-determine-worth)

Comment: It's not heavy, it's more like stubborn :P

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54576/how-could-thors-hammer-mj%c3%b6llnir-be-forged-in-the-heart-of-a-dying-star

Comment: Similar and matching question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16568/how-was-loki-not-crushed-by-mjolnir

Answer (score 9):

It's not that Mjolnir is heavy, it's that it's immobile.  The only one who can lift it is Thor, and as you see when Thor lifts it, it weighs as much as a normal hammer.  It's just that when anyone else tries to lift it (excepting Steve **cough**), the hammer does not move.

Comment: Mjolnir can be lifted by anyone who is "worthy".  Thor, Cap, the Medic who handed Thor the hammer when he was on a stretcher.  Based on that evidence, I assume there may be more people in the world that could lift and use it.

Comment: “as you see when Thor lifts it, it weighs as much as a normal hammer” — is that true? Surely Thor’s a bit stronger than your average guy, especially when he’s wielding the hammer.

Comment: @thorkia I've heard people mention that medic before.  When did that happen?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was torn on how to describe that.  I figure it weighs as much as an Asgardian hammer, which is about what we'd expect a hammer to weigh, but maybe a little heavier since they tend to be stronger than humans?

Comment: @Keen: I guess for all we know it could even be lighter.

Comment: @Nerrolken https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90608/when-did-a-paramedic-lift-mj%C3%B6lnir

Answer (score 2):

It's not the weight, but the Odin's enchantment which makes Thor's hammer unliftable by unworthy ones.

Remember, Hulk who is equally or more powerful than Thor tried to lift the hammer in *Avengers* movie (on Helicarrier), but failed.

**Update:**
In the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie, it has been revealed that

> Mjolnir is actually lightweight. Thor told this to Vision. Low weight allows better swinging.

Comment: An interesting fact from Comics: Captain American once became worthy to lift Thor's hammer... :)

Comment: Did Cap "become" worthy, as in did something about him change, or did he simply discover that he'd been worthy all along?

Comment: @discovery Except that that was HYDRA Cap, and it later was re-re-retconned that that wasn't actually Mjolnir. Or something.