# When did a paramedic lift Mjölnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, episode-identification, mjolnir

I've seen [numerous](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/2013/11/brief-guide-everyone-whos-ever-lifted-thors-hammer/#page/1) [references](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=12958126900A09588100&page=0) on the [internet](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/1qhhpy/how_much_brute_strength_is_needed_to_lift_mjolnir/) to an [event](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/6.854311-4-Marvel-Universe-Continuity-Gags-We-Actually-Want-to-See) where a [paramedic](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/thor-153/can-anyone-tell-me-who-all-has-lifted-thors-hammer-417915/?page=2) picked up Mjölnir and handed it to an injured Thor. The clear implication is that this unnamed medic was *unknowingly* worthy of the power of Thor.

---

The fact that no-one can identify where this scene is located makes me wonder whether it's simply someone's [headcanon](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/headcanon).

Can anyone identify this scene or, failing that where this urban (comic) legend originated?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that if the pictures of the paramedic existed, someone would have posted them online by now.  Everyone talks about it, but no one can back it up with pictures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[/u/DominizZle](https://www.reddit.com/u/DominizZzle) of Reddit [found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhocD.jpg) what [several people agree to be](https://www.reddit.com/r/whowouldwin/comments/3i7jtw/speed_equalized_thor_vs_lord_beerus/cudzju4) the scene in question in **Thor (1998) #35**. Several details are different than in the most common recountings, so this still may not be the correct scene, but I figured I'd throw it onto the pile.

[image: Lifting Mjolnir 1]
[image: Lifting Mjolnir 2]

Comment: I feel almost certain this is the scene that people are discussing

Answer (score 11):

I think you could be referring to Jake Olson, a EMT who was Thor's mortal identity after the Heroes Reborn/Heroes Return events of the late 90's. He first appeared in Thor vol2 #1. This does not quite fit with your description, but it is the only EMT I know of linked to the Thor story.

For the character's history check out the [Marvel database wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jake_Olson_(Earth-616)).

[image]

I have not read any Thor recently so I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm. This could easily be it. Although [an EMT is not a paramedic](https://www.cpc.mednet.ucla.edu/node/27) there's more than a passing similarity in the descriptions

Comment: Downvoted because I know this is not what Op referred to. I remember seeing a screen cap of a first responder casually passing Thor his hammer during a battle, not using it or turning into thor.

Comment: @cde - the op upvoted it, but you downvote it because it isn't what the op was talking about?  Weird, but okay.  As far as your memory of seeing the screen cap, if you can't find the image, it is only what you *think* you remember seeing.  A lot like the legendary shot of Luke Skywalker missing the first throw of his grappling hook in Star Wars, which everyone claims to remember but which never actually happened.

Answer (score 9):

I think people are conflating a few different events.

1. Thor's alter ego was an EMT or paramedic for a time.
2. There is a scan, available on Google images, of someone handing Mjolnir to terrible 1990's Thor, Thor saying thank you, then basically going "WTF JUST HAPPENED?" You can't see who is handing it to him in this scan, but apparently it was Wonder Woman.  In this scan, Thor does indeed seem to be injured after a serious brawl.

This is the more common and easy to find panel

[image]

And this is the harder to find preceding panel, revealing that the mysterious person was Wonder Woman.
[image]

3. There are other images where a normal looking guy in street clothes is standing next to Thor, picks up Mjolnir, and uses it to defend himself, apparently a story where Thor and his alter ego were separated and able to exist alongside each other.

[image]

Put all of that together and you might end up with a headcanon scenario where everyone thinks they remember seeing a paramedic hand Mjolnir to Thor. A lot like the infamous nonexistent scene in Star Wars where Luke misses his first throw of his grappling hook.

*Note:  I don't think it is out of the question for a paramedic to lift Mjolnir, necessarily;  he would be trying to help Thor, have good intentions, and be a decent person who had devoted his life to helping others in time of need.  This certainly counts as "worthiness" in my book, but who knows if Mjolnir and/or Odin would agree with me.*

*Thanks to Nerrolken for adding the first two pictures*

Comment: *"...apparently it was Wonder Woman."*  Wait, what?  Thor and Wonder Woman aren't even from the same company.  Was this some Marvel/DC crossover?  Where did you get that info for #2?

Comment: I believe it was a crossover in the 90's.

Comment: Just found the preceding panel, added it to your answer, and +1'd.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Even better

Comment: On a side note, how awful was the 1990's heavy metal hair band Thor?  The face mask, the super long hair, the cheesy leather straps around his gloves and legs for no reason, the chain attached to Mjolnir, the bare midriff, the huge shoulder pads, the fingerless gloves themselves...  Just horrible.  It is almost impossible to think of anything less cool than a helmet with wings, but somehow, they managed to find it - a weird clingy face plate that serves no apparent purpose.

Comment: I asked my brother, the biggest Thor fan I know, about the paramedic thing.  He says he doesn't remember ever seeing it happen, but he hasn't read a Thor comic in probably 20 years or more (neither have I).