# Can Magneto Lift Thor's Hammer?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto, mjolnir

One of my friends posted this on FaceBook:

[image]

and it got me wondering if Magneto's power over metal was strong enough to lift/control Mjolnir.

Comment: There is a difference between lifting/moving it, and *wielding* it. See my [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16595/1042) to my question: [Can Thor's hammer be wielded by anyone in outer space?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/can-thors-hammer-be-wielded-by-anyone-in-outer-space)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### No. We should be able to assure the Philoso-raptor, that as long as Magneto was within a [gravity well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_well), Mjolnir should be unable to be lifted. The enchantment is supposed to make Mjolnir unable to be lifted or moved by the unworthy. The enchantment should be able to discern if the magnetic force being used is connected to a worthy being.

[image: Magneto stops Thor's hammer from returning]

The worthiness clause might not stop Magneto from deflecting the thrown hammer, because it can be done (and has been done), but he should not be able to grab or hold the hammer physically and prevent it from returning to Thor. He has been able to create a barrier which keeps the weapon from immediately returning to Thor (see below). He certainly should not be allowed to hit Thor with it, in effect using it as a weapon.

[image: Magneto deflects all metallic objects, including Mjolnir]

He can and has pushed Mjolnir away using its metallic nature against it. This is still not truly wielding it, just moving it around by manipulating a magnetic field.

The recent exception with the Red Hulk beating Thor with his hammer in zero gravity has left the comic fans very, very unhappy. (As it should.)

I have one more Journey into Mystery image to show where Thor, using Mjolnir absorbs Magneto's magnetic field into itself and dispels it so that Thor can bring the pain to Magneto. Enjoy.

[image: Thor absorbing Magneto's magnetic protective shield.]

Comment: [I'm not so sure about that...](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/can-thors-hammer-be-wielded-by-anyone-in-outer-space/7141#7141)

Comment: Didn't the (green) Hulk pick up the hammer and use it against Thor?

Comment: If he does, it is never within a gravity well. He may be able to move it in zero g, but cannot truly wield it gaining access to its powers. Marvel is annoyingly inconsistent in its representations. See above link by DampeS8N.

Comment: What is a gravity well?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: it's the thing you're in that holds you to the ground, the gravitational field surrounding a heavy (not necessarily large) body like a planet.

Comment: Included a wikipedia link for Gravity Well in the body of the article. It may help.

Comment: What about [this answer of yours](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26471/13418) in which we clearly see Thor saying that even Mjollnir isn't immune to Magneto's powers ?

Comment: These examples seem to indicate that Magneto *can* move the hammer around, so I'm not sure how you're drawing the opposite conclusion.

Comment: Moving and lifting with the intent to use it are not the same thing. He can push it away. He cannot lift it, move it to use it as a weapon or control it. Any attempt at actually controlling it immediately makes his control invalid and it becomes immovable. Consider it a reflexive PUSH because of its magnetic nature. It is possible to push the hammer away while Thor is holding it, the same way someone might throw Thor away physically.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, in the Ultimates universe

In *Ultimatum* #5 and in *Ultimates 3* #5, Magneto was able to use his powers of magnetism to lift Mjolnir (something that, as other answers show, is not possible in the mainline universe).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly, he can *lift* it (what the question asked), but you say he's "controlling" it. Is he actually able to wield its powers?

Comment: @phantom42 You mean like call down lightning? I'll have to check the comic when I get a chance, but I think the answer is no. As I recall, he mostly keeps it around as a status symbol and uses it at one point as a blunt weapon. I've changed the wording of the answer to clarify that he can lift it, withiout implying that he can activate its other powers.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**

In the cinematic universe, where everything Asgard is really advanced technology instead of magic, there does exist a possibility that Magneto can "wield" it regardless of how worthy he is:

The current top answer to [Can Thor's hammer be wielded by anyone in outer space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/can-thors-hammer-be-wielded-by-anyone-in-outer-space) supposes the mechanism behind preventing anyone from wielding Thor's Hammer is quantum levitation - where the hammer "locks" itself into magnetic fields.  Since Magneto can manipulate magnetic fields, he would be able to move the hammer no matter where it locked itself into place.

Comment: On the other hand, if I recall correctly, Magneto can't appear in the cinematic universe (yet) because of licensing agreements with Fox.  However, this may hold true with other universes as well.

Comment: "licensing agreements with Fox" - Too bad Avengers/Xmen/others can't use this obviously powerful magic to lock up assorted baddies that need to be locked up :)

Answer (score 1):

He can lift it, if deemed worthy by Odin. The Hulk and Beta Ray Bill have both wielded it at full power... when acting in a worthy manner as deemed by Odin.
However, Odin giving Maggie the ok is highly unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the most fitting scenerio might be that he can lift it, but still can't wield the hammer's power, i.e. do the things Thor does with it.

Answer (score -2):

no one can do the things thor does with it because thor's powers come from him not from the hammer. he uses the hammer to focus his powers but the innate abikity to control the weather actually is duento who he is, not what he carries

Comment: Is that speculation or does thor say that somewhere?

Comment: According to [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Thor_complete_powers#ixzz2ELCwECY), you've got it exactly backwards; Thor is the conduit, not Mjolnir:  **Thor has a strong affinity with the forces of weather and acting as a conduct can channel Mjolnir's powers through himself allowing him to summon lighting from his hands.**