# Is anybody except Thor able to summon Mjölnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, mjolnir

It’s well-established that only people who are [“worthy”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4404/3567) are able to lift Mjölnir, and there are characters in both the comics and MCU (besides Thor) who have been able to lift it.

But Thor has an extra trick up his sleeve: he can summon Mjölnir if it’s not immediately within reach (for example, if he’s just thrown it at somebody). He reaches out a hand, and Mjölnir comes flying towards him. I've never come across anybody doing this in the MCU, nor the comics.

**Has anybody else been able to summon Mjölnir in this way, or is it exclusive to Thor?**

Comment: Excluding Odin you mean? He willed Mjölnir out of Thor's hand, after all?

Comment: @BMWurm …I had totally forgotten that scene. But yes, let’s exclude Odin.

Comment: The various Thor corps  members, Beta Ray Bill, possibly anyone deemed worthy, etc. All the powers of Thor, remember?

Comment: [Related](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/108/was-the-mj%c3%b6lnir-usable-by-only-the-worthy?rq=1), but of a different ilk.

Comment: @cde I am unfamiliar with the Thor corps, so that could be a basis for an answer.

Comment: @alexwlchan it was BRB, Thunderstrike, Thor 2099 and Thor Thor for a while during two mini-series. Nothing like the Green Lantern or Nova Corps. But answered.

Comment: Are you talking about Marvel comics, movies, or the actual Norse mythos? Thor the Norse Demigod predates Marvel by almost a thousand years. Thor was also part of Dungeons and Dragons, as well as many many books. I'm not sure which Thor you are speaking of,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone deemed worthy will have all the powers of Thor. This is the consistent power of Mjölnir's binding enchantment through all of Marvel Media. Multiple characters have become Thor or Thor-like, not just Thor Odinson. This includes Beta Ray Bill, Thunderstrike (Eric Masterson), Dargo Ktor (Thor 2099), Thor Girl, Throg (Simon Walterson/Puddlegulp), and 2014 Thor (Jane Foster) have all either carried the Mantle (Title) of Thor at one point, including wielding Mjölnir and it's essential equal copies (Storm Breaker, Thunder Strike, etc).

Including that power is the ability to control or command their hammer as they see fit. The most recent example is Thor Foster playing keep away:

[image]

Keep in mind, at some points, Thor was cursed with a time limit, so if he did not pull the hammer back in time, after 1 minute or so, he would lose his powers as Thor. He would then have to pick up the hammer manually instead of calling it to him. Various by medium.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a huge cheat, but Dr. Strange is able to "summon" Mjölnir in a fashion. Source: *Strange Tales #123*.

[image: Get over here!]

Also, in the Ultimate Universe, Magneto is able to lift Mjölnir through magnetism. [There is an answer in another question about that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123572/33542). Sources: *Ultimatum #5* and *Ultimates 3 #5*.

[image: Magneto holding Mjölnir][image: Magneto holding Mjölnir]

Therefore I suppose that he could pull Mjölnir towards himself, as long as the mallet is within the range of his magnetic powers.