# Can Mjolnir be lifted & wielded by anyone if Thor is touching it?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

In *The Big Bang Theory* episode [The Bakersfield Expedition](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bakersfield_Expedition), Penny, Amy, and Bernadette are having an argument if Thor's hammer:

1. Can be **lifted** by anyone in space.
2. Can be **lifted** & **wielded** by anyone if Thor is touching it.

The first argument is settled in [Can Thor's hammer be wielded by anyone in outer space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/can-thors-hammer-be-wielded-by-anyone-in-outer-space).

But the second argument remains ***unsolved***.  Can Thor's hammer be **lifted** & **wielded** by anyone if Thor is touching it?

Comment: Keep in mind it's not the weight/mass of Mjolnir that prevents people from wielding it, it's the enchantments. So I suppose, a follow up would be--what happens in zero-g? Does Mjolnir remain in a fixed position in space when Thor isn't touching it? Or, when in zero-g, does it float around like anything else and just limits the hammer's "special abilities" if someone tries to wield it?

Comment: That question is partially answered in the *link* given above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, in Marvel comics and cartoons Thor's hammer can be lifted and wielded by others if Thor is touching it. The trick is that they have to be strong enough to overpower Thor.  The Hulk has done this in a recent issue of *Avengers Assemble* (#4):

[image: Hulk v. Thor: Avengers Assemble]

The same thing happened earlier in the *Hulk: Let the Battle Begin* one-shot.

[image: Hulk: Let the Battle Begin]

Finally, there are many, many instances of the Hulk either lifting or tossing Thor while Thor was wielding Mjolnir.  Here are just a few of those.

[image: Hulk vs. Thor Animated Movie]

[image: Hulk slaps Thor down]

[image: Hulk headlocks Thor]

[image: Hulk lifts Thor]

[image: Hulk punches Thor]

Comment: To be fair, that's the Hulk, who can actually lift Mjolnir *by himself* when he's angry enough.

Comment: No he cannot.  It's one of Hulk's REPEATED frustrations that this bit of metal will not be budged by his musclepower.

Answer (score 7):

The second point is up to interpretation, based on how you define "lift up".

This also depends on which interpretation of Thor you are considering: The original folklore has Thor's hammer stolen at least once, something I'd consider impossible, if only the worthy can lift it.

As for Marvel's Thor I'd say anyone (strong enough) could lift both at once. Otherwise no bad guy would be able to throw or kick Thor around as long as he's in possession of his hammer. I've only seen the old animated series years ago, but I think I remember him being kicked around at least once.