# Can you lift Thor when he is holding Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

I was wondering:

If no one can lift Mjolnir (Thor's hammer), can one lift Thor while he is holding his hammer?

Comment: not really a duplicate, but i found my answer there

Comment: Even if the question isn't the same, if the information/answer is covered within then it's considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

I found the answer in some of the pictures in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31338/31574)

Comment: Which kind of begs the question if you hit someone with Thor what happens!?