# How many people can lift Thor's hammer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, mjolnir

How many people have the power to wield Mjolnir?

I know of 5:

> Odin
> Thor
> Hela (aside from stopping it, there is a painting of her holding it in the "great hall" when she unveils the covered ceiling)
> Vision
> Captain America

Is there anybody else who has picked up Thor's hammer?

Comment: Is this just within the MCU continuity? It may be helpful if we restrict it to that.

Comment: Yes, but I'd also be interested in the comic side.

Comment: I think that Elevator is also worthy.

Comment: @RonBeyer you’ve tagged this with MCU which indicates you are only asking about that and asking about the comics as a whole might be too broad.

Comment: Beta Rey Bill is most famous from the comics..

Comment: Who _hasn’t_ picked it up!

Comment: Add to the list "anyone that can lift Thor".

Comment: @IanMacDonald [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31331/58193).

Comment: The 3rd in your list held Mjolnir prior to the "worthiness" enchantment Odin put on it.

Comment: I saw a comic where Mr. Rogers was holding it. Oh, right, MCU....  ;-)

Comment: I saw a video and Consuela can lift it to clean under it with the lemon pledge.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Technically* anyone pre-*Thor*, so pre-2011, would have been able to wield Mjolnir as the worthiness enchantment was only placed on it then. However, as we only get a very brief glimpse of this time period we don't actually see anyone else wield Mjolnir.

> **Odin:** Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.
>
> <sub>*Thor*, Mjolnir's enchantment</sub>

---

Onto those we've actually seen wield it though.

#### Thor

Obviously Thor wields Mjolnir and although he temporarily loses the ability to wield Mjolnir in *Thor*, he becomes worthy again at the end of the film.

[image: Thor wielding Mjolnir]

#### Odin

He can clearly be seen wielding Mjolnir, he does so when he banishes Thor and actually can still wield it after he places the enchantment upon it, so he is clearly also worthy of Mjolnir... which makes sense since he placed the enchantment.

#### Vision

When Vision first comes to be he held Mjolnir straight away and passed it back to Thor. To be 100% clear on if he "wields" it though we see in the battle against all of Ultron that he does use the hammer.

[image: Vision wielding Mjolnir]

However, as Steve and Tony note it is possible that because Vision is artificial "different rules" apply - though he is part living tissue.

> **Steve Rogers:** The rules have changed.
>
> **Tony Stark:** We're dealing with something new.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Well, the Vision's artificial intelligence.
>
> **Tony Stark:** A machine.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** So it doesn't count.
>
> **Tony Stark:** No. It's not like a person lifting the hammer.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Right. Different rules for us.
>
> **Tony Stark:** Nice guy, but artificial.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Thank you.
>
> **Thor:** If he can wield the hammer, he can keep the Mind Stone. It's safe with the Vision and these days, safe is in short supply.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** But if you put the hammer in an elevator...
>
> **Tony Stark:** It would still go up.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Elevator's not worthy.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

#### Hela

As we see in *Thor: Ragnarok* Hela can stop Mjolnir in its tracks even with the enchantment on it. This is more likely to do with her own powers rather than her being worthy though of course because she doesn't act worthy. Although as we see on the mural she actually wielded Mjolnir in the past before Thor's time when conquering the Realms with Odin.

[image: Hela stopping Mjolnir in its tracks] [image: Mural showing Hela holding Mjolnir]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Steve Rogers/Captain America

He was always worthy, ever since the scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* where we see him move the hammer just a nudge, however, he chose not to pick it up. See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217579/58193) of mine to a related question for evidence on that. However, we don't actually see him wield Mjolnir until the Battle of Earth in *Avengers: Endgame* where he picks it up to fight Thanos.

---

Lastly, I think it is worth noting that Jane Foster is set to reappear in *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2021) as Thor and so it is possible she will also wield Mjolnir. It was even teased that this would be the case in the reveal at San Diego Comic-Con where she took the stage with Mjolnir in hand. Whilst this isn't conclusive proof as there are no set pics or footage released yet it is a strong indicator Jane Foster will also wield Mjolnir.

[image: Natalie Portman on stage with Taika Waititi and Kevin Feige holding Mjolnir]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

On a slightly different note the upcoming Disney+ series *What If...?* has had the first episode revealed to be about what if Peggy Carter had taken the super soldier serum and not Steve Rogers. Whilst it's not entirely clear what this will entail, if it shows Peggy in the "future" as Captain America we might see her wielding Mjolnir. Although of course this isn't the main MCU continuity so shouldn't be taken as such.

Comment: The mural of Hela wielding it "in the past" might be showing a time before the worthiness enchantment was added.

Comment: @armb There's no might about it, it was before the worthiness enchantment was added as it was only added in _Thor_.

Comment: I may be nitpicking, but the enchantment doesn't mention the ability to wield Mjolnir, only that whomever *does* wield Mjolnir gains the power of Thor and that they only gain the power of Thor if they're worthy. It might seem trivial, but in Thor: Ragnarok Odin says that Thor's powers don't come from the hammer; it just helps Thor channel his powers. It sort of seems to me like the power to wield Mjolnir is an ability of Thor's, and if you're worthy of having Thor's powers you can wield Mjolnir, so the enchantment channels Thor's powers to the wielder but not a restriction on who can wield it.

Comment: I'm not sure that lines up with Hela and Odin wielding Mjolnir... but perhaps the ability to wield Mjolnir is a trait of the lineage of Odin? Or am I missing something huge? lol  I'd love to know if I'm off base :D.

Comment: also, Harry Potter

Comment: *"...[Odin] is clearly also worthy of Mjolnir... which makes sense since he placed the enchantment."*   [Ah, but can Odin enchant a hammer so hard that he cannot wield it??](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox)

Comment: This may just be my interpretation, but I always thought that the reason Hela was able to so easily stop and destroy Mjolnir was that she had a prior claim to it, as it had been hers for centuries before it became Thor's.  So he was unknowingly using the worst possible weapon to attack her-- one that "remembered" it had once belonged to Hela.

Answer (score 11):

As the querent indicated that they're interested in the comics continuity as well as the MCU, I've quoted the list from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics)#Wielders):

### Individuals in the primary continuity

- [Thor Odinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics))
- [Roger "Red" Norvell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Thor_(Marvel_Comics)#Red_Norvell)
- [Beta Ray Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill)
- [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America)
- [Eric Masterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderstrike_(Eric_Masterson)) (aka Thunderstrike)
- [Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(comics)) (Thor's father)
- Bor (Thor's grandfather)
- Buri (also known as Tiwaz, Thor's great-grandfather)
- [Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(comics))
- [Jane Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Foster_(comics))
- [Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_Girl)
- [The Destroyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyer_(Thor))
- [Steve Rogers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America#Hydra_Agent) (The Hydra agent version, only possible after the cosmic cube rewrote reality to change the nature of the enchantment)

## Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999)

- [Thor Odinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe))
- [Odin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(Marvel_Comics))
- [Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_(Marvel_Comics))
- [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Rogers_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe))

## Sentient constructs (non-sentient machines apparently cannot) in the primary continuity

- [Zarrko the Tomorrow Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarrko)'s mining robot
- [Air-Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-Walker)
- [Awesome Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_Android)
- The hammer has been lifted by Earth itself when animated by magical means.

## Characters from outside the primary comic book continuity

- Conan the Barbarian
- Dargo Ktor (Future Thor)
- (Old) Rick Jones of Hulk Future Imperfect
- Loki
- Magni
- Rogue
- Miguel O'Hara (Spider-Man 2099)
- Professor X (In Issue 69 of X-Men)
- Magneto (comics)
- Hyperion (comics) (in ultimate comics)
- Red Hulk
- Spider-Man
- Doctor Doom
- Valkyrie (Marvel Comics) (in Ultimate comics)
- Ororo Munroe
- Bruce Banner
- Deadpool
- Sarah Rogers (Crusader, daughter of Steve Rogers and Rogue)
- Woden
- Alex Power
- Superman, temporarily. After the battle he can no longer do so; Thor explains that Odin's enchantment allows "a very few worthies" to lift the hammer in "desperate hours".
- Wonder Woman (non-canonical)
- Black Widow
- Silver Surfer

Comment: Steve Rogers is not Captain America in the primary continuity?

Comment: What about Storm? https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-8fb60a0810efe2e93bf8075fee5063bb

Comment: Why is Hela not in the MCU category?

Comment: The question is solely about the MCU not all of Marvel

Comment: @thelethalcarrot: the querent indicated otherwise.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I saw, however, it's tagged to scope to the MCU specifically and the wording is pretty much from an MCU only perspective. It would also be pretty broad to ask about all of Marvel and I've asked them to clarify on the question.

Comment: @Taladris He sort-of was, sort-of wasn't at the time. It was during Secret Empire and the  'Captain Hydra' controversy

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat (cc Fuzzy and Taladris) Steve has picked up Mjolnir a few times, not only because of the Captain Hydra part (where both Captain Hydra _and_ Steve actually wield it) see [my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217579/58193) for details.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot there's no harm in going for the extra credit if the question has been answered. This way we can point to this answer when someone asks the more generic one and save effort by creating a dupe.

Comment: @Mindwin We shouldn't close the more general one to the more specific one of course. And sure there's no harm in it but I've come to expect more from this site than a copy and paste from Wikipedia with no supporting evidence. If this answer had included evidence for everything or at least focused on one universe with evidence it would be _a lot_ better.

Comment: Wouldn't an elevator qualify as a "non-sentient machine"?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: You are right. That was lazy of me.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Really? Darn it, and I just bought a new keyboard just for the "copy" and "paste" macros so I could rule StackExchange!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman what if it's a Sirius Cybernetics Corporation Happy Vertical People Transporter?